# Getting values and total keys they are present in python

Tags: python

i have a dic in this form:

```
dic = {'movie1':{('bob',1),('jim',3),('dianne',4)},
'movie2': {('dianne',1),('bob',3),('asz',4)}}
```

it consists of of `movie_name` as `keys`, and tuples of `values` with `(name,score)` for each moviee

i want to convert this into:

```
{ 'bob': { 'movie1': 1,'movie2': 3},
  'jim': {'movie1': 3},
  'dianne': {'movie1': 4,'movie2': 1},
   'asz': {'movie2: 4} }
```

i.e  movie reviewed by each person, and the score for each movie.

Im lookingo for a function in which i can pass my dictionary 'dic' and it gives this result

What i tried was:

```
def reviewer_rank(db):
    main_l=[]
    for i in dic.values():
        temp_l = list(i)
        temp_l=dict(temp_l).keys()
        main_l.extend(temp_l)
    return main_l
```

i was able to get all the names of the dict in the list

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @stybl yes, i am adding that too in my que, i've tried using counter(collections library)

Comment: Why do you use a set instead of a dictionary?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that is the datatype i am working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to avoid some bumpy code checking for the existence of each name in the result `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for movie, scores in dic.items():
  for name, score in scores:
    d[name][movie] = score
d
# defaultdict: {'bob': {'movie1': 1, 'movie2': 3}, 'asz': {'movie2': 4}, 'jim': {'movie1': 3}, 'dianne': {'movie1': 4, 'movie2': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the key-value tuples `k,vs` of the outer dictionary, and then for every tuple `u, s` in the value `vs`, you assign `result[u][k]` with `s`.

Since it is not certain that `u` is already in the `result` dictionary, we better use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
for k, vs in dic.items():
    for u, s in vs:
        result[u][k] = s
```

You can later cast the `result` back to a dict, with:

```
dict(result)
```

Note however that a `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so all dictionary operations are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive solution. It is just a simple case of looping over your input dict restructuring it into a new one with the required structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import defaultdict

dic = {'movie1': {('bob', 1), ('jim', 3), ('dianne', 4)},
       'movie2': {('dianne', 1), ('bob', 3), ('asz', 4)}}

raters = defaultdict(dict)
for movie, ratings in dic.items():
    for rater, rating in ratings:
        raters[rater][movie] = rating
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your current data structure into tuples, and create a new dict of dict based on that. Do that with a generator, and it will yield one item at a time.

Using *namedtuple* you can access your data using strings instead of ints, which is more readable.

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

entries = namedtuple('Entries', 'name movie score')
new_dic = defaultdict(dict)

keys = (entries(name[0], k, name[1]) for k, v in dic.items() for name in v)

for item in keys:
       new_dic[item.name][item.movie] = item.score
```